# Multidimensional String Array Assignment C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, variable-assignment

I have a preallocated multidimensional string array declared as follows:

```
std::string test[5][169] = { { },{ },{ },{ },{ } };
```

I need to make a function that accepts as input a string like this:

```
{"abc","dac","fab" },{"hbv","acd" },{ "ccd","ahn","agt","atr"},{"are"},{ }
```

and puts correctly values in the array(as I'm assigning it);

The problem is I can't pass a 2D+ array as parameter to a function in C++
and can't do assignment for multidimensional array like this:

```
test= {"abc","dac","fab" },{"hbv","acd" },{ "ccd","ahn","agt","atr"},{"are"},{ };
```

I'm looking for a method to put correctly values into the array.

I also tried to use `std::vector` and all I solved the problem just for one dimensional array:

```
std::vector<std::string> test;
test = {"abc","dac","fab" };
```

But I'd need something like

```
std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > test;
test = {"abc","dac","fab" },{"hbv","acd" },{ "ccd","ahn","agt","atr"},{"are"},{ };
```

Comment: Are you trying to assign like `test = {},{},{},{},...'` or like this `test = {{}, {}, {}, {}, ...};`. Big difference.

Comment: I was doing assignment w/o the external {}, thank you for reply

Answer (score 1):

add an additional pair of braces in your last line and you should be done:

```
 test = {{"abc","dac","fab" },{"hbv","acd" },{ "ccd","ahn","agt","atr"},{"are"},{ }};
```

Comment: I was missing the starting/ending {/} in the assignment, thank you.